# App Engine Connected Android Project

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm missing the App Engine Connected Android Project option when I go to File->New->Other->Android. I'm running Eclipse Helios on Win Xp.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you already installed the Google Plugin for Eclipse (GPE)? What version? App Engine Connected Android Project is new in 2.4, which is still in beta. Instructions for installing the beta version (basically you just have to use a slightly different software site) are at http://code.google.com/eclipse/beta/docs/download.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I was able to finally find the link to download this beta version. But I can't connect to the cloud, which is running on 127.0.0.1 on my machine,since the emulator is running in its private network and has IP 10.0.2.15. So there's a routing issue. However, they were showing an example of App Engine Connected Android Project at the conference using an emulator.

Comment: Hopefully by now you've found the info you need. 127.0.0.1 is just the loopback address on any hardware. I read elsewhere on SO that the host running the emulator gets 10.0.2.2. Try firing up the App Engine component and then trying to connect to it at 10.0.2.2 through your AVD's web browser. Might just be a matter of pointing the Android project to that IP instead of to the deployed project at appspot.com